# Объединение одномерных массивов

Tags: php

Есть 2 массива:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 99
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 65

)
Array
(
    [0] => Text1
    [1] => Text2
    [2] => Text3
    [3] => Text4

)
```

Можно ли как то обьединить их в один вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Text1 => 8
    [1] => Text2 => 99
    [2] => Text3 => 0
    [3] => Text4 => 65

)
```

Или как-нибудь удобнее, чтобы суметь вывести в php
Text1 = 8 и т.д?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно я не так объяснил, что хотел получить, но ответ нашел

```
 $result = array_map(function($text, $num){
   return [ 
    'text' => $text,
    'num' => $num,
   ];
   // return "$text $num"; 
 }, $text, $num);

 print_r($result);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => Text1
            [num] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => Text2
            [num] => 99
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => Text3
            [num] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [text] => Text4
            [num] => 65
        )


)
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте **[array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php)**:

```
$keys = ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4'];
$vals = [8, 99, 0, 65];

$array = array_combine($keys, $vals);
```

Результат:

```
array (
  'Text1' => 8,
  'Text2' => 99,
  'Text3' => 0,
  'Text4' => 65
)
```